# I have installed with yum install python-devel ,but still can not find the Python.h file

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-3.x, yum

I have run the command `yum install python-devel`,and the output is :

```
yum install python-devel
Loaded plugins: presto, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python-devel.i686 0:2.6.4-25.fc13 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
```

but when I `locate Python.h`, it did not output anything
Please share your solution,if you know the reason ,Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing a package does not automatically update the locatedb. You are seeing nothing strange. If you want to update the locatedb manually, run `updatedb`.

Comment: what you say was what i want .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you run

```
$ rpm -ql python-devel | grep -i python.h
```

you will get

```
/usr/include/python2.6/Python.h
```

Comment: can you share with me why I can not find it with locate it ?